# Binning with negative weights

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have a long list of events consisting of pairs

```
     {{e_1,w_1},{e_2,w_2}, ....{e_n,w_n}}
```

I want to bin the energies e_i and then sum the 'weights' w_i of all events in a particular bin of energy e. The w_i are not true weights, because some of them can be negative. Thus I cannot use WeightedData. 
What is an efficient way to achieve this binning with 'weight' summation in each bin?

Here is some example data:

```
em = {1, 1.5, 3., 4., 2.1, 7.3, 6., 8.5, 9.9, 5.7}
w = {10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 10, 20, 5, -7, 8}
```

The bins are 0-5 and 5-10, and the result should be {25, 36}.

Comment: `GroupBy` based on a `Round`ed `e` value?

Comment: `Total[Map[#[[1]]#[[2]]&, {{e_1,w_1},{e_2,w_2}, ....{e_n,w_n}}]`?

Comment: Example data would be great.

Comment: So, here is an example:

      em = {1, 1.5, 3., 4., 2.1, 7.3, 6., 8.5, 9.9, 5.7}
      w = {10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 10, 20, 5, -7, 8}

Now we bin this into two em-bins 0-5 and 5- 10. in each of these bins I need the sum of the weights of the energies in that bin. The result should then be:

{25,43}

Comment: sorry, correction: the result should be {25,36}

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: This solution gives only one number: I need the sum of weights in each bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) (using M10.3+):

```
Total[
    Nearest[em -> w, {2.5, 7.5}, {Infinity, 2.5}],
    {2}
]
```

> {25, 36}

Comment: Curiously this code crashes *Mathematica* 10.1.

Answer (score 5):

#### [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)

```
em = {1, 1.5, 3., 4., 2.1, 7.3, 6., 8.5, 9.9, 5.7};
w = {10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 10, 20, 5, -7, 8} ;
emw = Transpose[{em, w}];

Values @ GroupBy[emw, Quotient[First@#, 5] &, Total]
```

> {{11.6, 25}, {37.4, 36}}

To get just the weight totals

```
Values @ GroupBy[emw, Quotient[First@#, 5]&->Last , Total]
```

> {25, 36}

#### [`BinLists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinLists.html?q=BinLists)

It is more convenient to specify bins with `BinLists`

```
Total[Join @@@ BinLists[emw, 5, Abs[Subtract @@ MinMax @ w]],{2}]
```

> {{11.6, 25}, {37.4, 36}}

Comment: Using 10^7 pairs, your first version takes about 0.5 s on my machine (M12), the second about 0.7 s, and the last is much slower at 3.3 s.